# #pragma AVRT_CODE_BEGIN - what does it mean?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I maintain some codes, there are lines like:

```
#pragma AVRT_CODE_BEGIN   
//some code
#pragma AVRT_CODE_END
```

I can't understand them, 
I googled it, but got nothing, except a code sample:[Click me](http://read.pudn.com/downloads95/sourcecode/zip/388072/wmvv9_dec/slimc/sp2/scrunch/wmv2/decoder_c9/c/msmton.c__.htm)
May you know AVRT_CODE_BEGIN and AVRT_CODE_END mean? 
please tell me. Thank you very much.

Comment: I think it is a hint to the compiler to optimize code with "real time" performance constraints, like processing audio. But I do not know what it really does.

Answer (score 0):

There are compiler directives to emit code into a particular linker segment, instead of the default linker segment, for Audio processing with the AVRT library. It appears to be an internal Microsoft feature. The segments exist probably for optimization or security. I found this header file that shows the meaning:

ftp://ns432777.ip-37-59-27.eu/Program%20Files%20%28x86%29/Windows%20Kits/8.0/Include/um/baseaudioprocessingobject.h

```
// These are copied out of the old AvRt.h file.
#define AVRT_CODE_BEGIN   code_seg( push, "RT_CODE" )
#define AVRT_DATA_BEGIN   data_seg( push, "RT_DATA" )
#define AVRT_BSS_BEGIN    bss_seg( push, "RT_BSS" )
#define AVRT_CONST_BEGIN  const_seg( push, "RT_CONST" )
#define AVRT_VTABLES_BEGIN AVRT_CONST_BEGIN
#define AVRT_CODE_END   code_seg( pop )
#define AVRT_DATA_END   data_seg( pop )
#define AVRT_BSS_END    bss_seg( pop )
#define AVRT_CONST_END  const_seg( pop )
#define AVRT_VTABLES_END AVRT_CONST_END
#define AVRT_DATA __declspec(allocate("RT_DATA"))
#define AVRT_BSS __declspec(allocate("RT_BSS"))
#define AVRT_CONST __declspec(allocate("RT_CONST"))
```